# how to Use html table values (generated from a query) in a new query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i've currently got a php/html table which holds values generated from a query:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['disease'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>
        <a href='result1.php' class='button1'>View Details</a>
        <a href='#' class='button1'>Book Appointment</a>
      </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>"
```

;

What i would like to do is enable the user to click on the 'View Details' button to initiate another query (which is processed in result1.php):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT definition FROM tbl_disease WHERE disease = '" . $_GET[' $row[disease'] . "' ;  ")
or die(mysql_error());
```

This query should get details (definition) based on table values from the previous php page. At the moment i get an error on '$_GET[' $row[disease'] .'. Im new to this so I'm unsure if this is the right way to go about it?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you need to parse the value onto result1.php  `<a href='result1.php?disease=$row['disease']' class='button1'>View Details</a>`

Comment: We just don't do it like this anymore

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `result1.php` you have `$_GET[' $row[disease']` but in the code with

```
<a href='result1.php' class='button1'>View Details</a>
```

you don't send the `GET` value.
Change the above to:

```
<a href='result1.php?disease=".$row['disease']."' class='button1'>View Details</a>
```

and in `result1.php`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT definition FROM tbl_disease WHERE disease = '".$_GET['disease']."' ;  ")
```

To make it the right way with security just as @Dragon mentioned you should never do operations on mysql with $GET/$POST and other without proper formating.

For more info: 
[mysql_escape_string](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_real_escape_string.asp) [htmlentities](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp) 
[filter_input](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_input.asp).

Comment: another person wanting the OP to get hacked

Comment: Then you would not answer to the OP's topic.

Comment: Thank you, the code works! However I don't quite know how to properly format the operations. shouldn't it be ok just as long as I'm not sending sensitive data?

Comment: It dosen't have to be you that send sensitive data. For example with firebug someone can edit the a href code and get what he wants. Good practice is to always secure your code and filter the GET/POST and other.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td>
        <a href='result1.php?disease=".$row['disease']."' class='button1'>View Details</a>
        <a href='#' class='button1'>Book Appointment</a>
      </td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

this is how you can pass the disease but you should be more careful when you write your query you should check a bit about mysqli_real_escape_string here is the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php  there might be better ways to use but this is not bad either. hope this helped

Answer (score -1):

From your original code, you are trying to access a URL variable via the GET method named, but you are not passing that variable to the URL as your href doesn't include it.

Try setting a variable within the URL of your link on the first page like below:

```
<a href='result1.php?disease=" . $row['disease'] . "' class='button1'>View Details</a>
```

This will pass a variable named `$disease` to your result1.php page via the GET method. You would then be able to access the variable by using `$_GET['disease']`.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT definition FROM tbl_disease WHERE disease = '" . $_GET['disease'] . "'");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: so you want his site to get hacked?